# Low Quality Posts Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I recently failed this audit in the LQP queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20647014

Now seeing any action from a moderator in the comments should have been a red flag, and I probably should have clicked over to the question to see if it was an audit.

But the moderator comment: **"...perhaps they weren't spamming there, but answering there as well? (like here)"** is logically equivalent to **"They are answering here, perhaps they were there as well"**

Although there is a link in the answer, it's relevant and not the only information provided.

Why would the moderator comment essentially: **"all clear, this answer is fine"** and then go ahead and mark it as spam?

I resent the fact that many audits are simply a matter of click on the question and see if the answer is still there. If the correct conclusion can't be drawn from what is shown on the audit screen, it shouldn't be used as an audit.

Answer (score 4):

> Why would the moderator comment essentially: "all clear, this answer is fine" and then go ahead and mark it as spam?

They didn't.  They said perhaps, and *asked a question* of whether or not it was appropriate, indicating they were unsure.  It seems that they investigated further and determined that it was in fact spam.

> Although there is a suspicious link in the answer, it's relevant and not the only information provided.

Which doesn't mean it's not spam.  The author could be affiliated with the product, having not disclosed it, or otherwise breaching the guidelines for appropriate promotion of a product.

You noticed several red flags, and they made you suspicious, but you failed to investigate further upon seeing those red flags.